# Consultar clientes que nuncan han hecho pedidos con MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Tengo dos colecciones:

Cliente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pedido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
db.producto.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"pedido",localField:"_id",foreignField:"id_cliente", as:"pedidos"}}]).pretty()
```

pero no hay ninguna salida de datos.

[Adjunto](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fCE9_a-wCstbA0aA9_q2ExztwbWaUc8L?usp=sharing) el resto de las colecciones y los archivos .json, para obtener mayores detalles.

Answer (score 0):

esta puede ser una forma, pero pueden hay varias formas de resolvela

```
db.cliente.aggregate([{$lookup: {from: "pedido",localField: "_id",foreignField: "id_cliente",as: "lista_pedido"}},{$match: {lista_pedido:[]}}]).pretty()
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).